# running npm install gives gyp err on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new to react and I'm trying to clone a git repository. I've tried to run `npm install` to install the dependencies but I got an error on the first try.

The first error was really long (about ~7500 lines of error code) and it was not explanatory. After a while I've realized that my node version was not the latest. It was `14.06`. I've tried to update it via `sudo npm cache clean -f`, `sudo npm install -g n`, `sudo n stable` but it downloaded the same version again. Then I found out that I need to install it via the ubuntu software application. After doing that my nodejs was indeed on version `v16.17.1` when I ran `node -v`.

However I'm still getting the same error when I run `npm install`. Then I saw somewhere that running `` will fixed it. I've tried it but it resulted in an error  I run `npm install` but this time the error code is much smaller and I can actually post it here.

**Here is the error code:**

```
turgut@turgut-N56VZ:~/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react$ npm install --nodedir=/node/src/
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated mini-create-react-context@0.4.1: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated react-resizable-box@2.1.0: CAUTION react-resizable-box is renamed to re-resizable. Please use re-resizable if you want to use latest package.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.12.1:  This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated vis@4.21.0-EOL: Please consider using https://github.com/visjs
npm WARN deprecated core-js-pure@3.20.3: core-js-pure@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js-pure.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.20.3: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /tmp/postinstall-358bd37b.sh
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir compiling against specified --nodedir dev files: /node/src/
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:10374) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/node/src/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/node/src/',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/node/src/$(Configuration)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: /node/src/common.gypi not found (cwd: /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-48-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/turgut/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/videoo-react/node_modules/react-app-rewire-sass-rule/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

What is this error and how do I fix this? I don't understand anything from this error code. My node-gyp should be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

This is about your node version, matching it with the development environment's node version would solve the problem.